# Mistakenly wrote "dollars" in dollars section of check

Tags: check, paycheck, personal-check

When filling a check, I wrote the alphabetic value correctly. However, I wrote "dollars" at its end (while it itself has this word).
Should I cross it out? Ignore it? Or rewrite the check?

Answer (score 5):

Ignore it. Having both a numeric and a written-out representation of the amount simply serves to confirm that the amount is correct, and to prevent tampering (e.g. recipient adds an extra 0 to the numeric amount, but the written amount says "One hundred" rather than "One thousand").

As long as it's clear what you meant it should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The worst option would be crossing it out. Banks get understandably nervous when they see a check with things crossed out, and it would probably not be honored.

If the intent of the check is clear, ignore it; if not, rewrite it.